# How can I suppress extra properties added by BreezeController?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, breeze

Following the [NoDB example](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb), I changed an existing WebAPI controller to use the `Breeze.WebApi2.BreezeController` annotation. This changes the JSON result from something really simple:

```
[{"Name":"Thing1","Description":"Description of Thing 1"},
{"Name":"Thing2","Description":"Another description"}]
```

To something a bit more complex and bandwidth-consuming:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"MyCompany.MyProduct.Models.ContentType, MyCompany.MyProduct","Name":"Thing1","Description":"Description of Thing 1"},
{"$id":"2","$type":"MyCompany.MyProduct.Models.ContentType, MyCompany.MyProduct","Name":"Thing2","Description":"Another description"}]
```

And as described in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323736/what-breeze-settings-are-needed-to-make-caching-work), the extra info doesn't actually provide metadata to the client. I still had to define that manually.

Given the above, two questions:

1. What purpose does the extra info serve if I still have to define metadata on the client?
2. Is there a way to suppress the extra properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $id, $type and $ref properties are added by Json.NET on the server during serialization. By default, The $type property is used by the Breeze client to determine what 'EntityType' to materialize into. the $id and $ref properties are used to handle object graphs so that the json for a referenced entity is never expressed more than once.  This can occur as a result of an EntityQuery 'expand' method call or in any number of complex projections via the 'select' method.

Breeze does not require these but if you suppress them ( via Json.NET settings on the server), then you will need to implement a client side 'jsonResultsAdapter' that handles all of the stuff mentioned above.

Comment: So just by adding the BreezeController annotation it changed the serialization method of the response? If breeze client uses $type why do I also need to manually define metadata on client?

Comment: Metadata is about more than just the name, it is data about the data type of every property, the relationships between entityTypes, and a lot more.  The $type simply lets the breeze client connect the serialized json to all of this other metadata. None of this metadata is natively available on the client unless it is either sent from the server ( the default) or created in code on the client.

Comment: The $type doesn't mean anything unless the client knows what that $type **is** - what fields it has, what the datatype and validation rules of each field are, what its primary key is, what its relationships are to other types.  All of that is defined in the metadata.